# React Router Dynamic nested Routes not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Here is the problem, I am using **react-router** when I try to access the dynamic link **/home/:subject** outside the    **subjectdshboard** component then it works fine but when I try to access the other dynamic route from the components navbar the links change, and nothing get rendered.
**For example**, If I access the subject physics from outside the **subjectdashboard** component its link looks like **home/physics** but if I try to access it's from the navbar of the component its link becomes **home/home/physics** and the component doesn't get rendered.**The Navbar is the same throughout the app**

```js
 const navItems = ["physics", "maths", "chemistry", "biology"];

navItems.map((item) => {
                    return (
                      <Link to={`home/${item}`} className="link">
                        <Typography
                          variant="h6"
                          noWrap
                          className={classes.title}
                        >
                          {item}
                        </Typography>
                      </Link>
                    );
                  })
```

and in the app component, the route is

```js
 <Route exact path="/home/:subject">
              <SubjectDashBoard />
            </Route>
```

Comment: Share code please

Comment: You need to put a slash at the start: `<Link to="/home/physics">` (without the preceding slash it's a relative link and the browser appends it to the current location)